# How do I change the text of the password strength widget in the Gigya registration & login screen?

Tags: passwords, gigya

My company uses Gigya for its Registration/authentication as a service provider, and recently we decided to change the password policy to no longer require "special characters". I've amended the regex in the policies section that enforces this, but the password strength widget still says the user needs to provide a special character. I've looked in the screen-set for Registration/Login & all it seems to have is a drop-down box on the password field where we can choose to have the strength widget above, below, to the left or to the right of the password. There doesn't seem to be anywhere I can edit this text. Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sussed it. You can't change the default message, BUT if you create a localization for the default language (eg: en), you can export the csv from that, which has within it a value called NUM_OF_THE_FOLLOWING_GROUPS, which contains the default text "%num of the following: An uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, a number, a special symbol". You can edit this and re-import it, and it will take effect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The text that displays when filling in a password is determined by the settings you have in the sites Policies under the Password settings (https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Policies#Policies-PasswordStrength).

You can override these settings by using the customLang property of the accounts.showScreenSet method (https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Customizing+Screen-Set+Error+Messages)

Comment: Hmm. Not sure that's the case - it's possible that it's supposed to be the case but I have a regex that requires lowercase, uppercase & numbers but no special characters in the policy, and a password strength widget that says I need lowercase, uppercase, numbers *and* special characters. If there's a way to set it by hand, this would be a lot easier I think.